# caching of jsp page at server side

Tags: java, jsp, caching

I am Using the following steps to cache the jsp page at server side defined in the following url  [caching of jsp at server side](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26576_01/doc.312/e24930/webapps.htm#beagw)

i have web-glue.jar in java build path, and tld as defined in the following steps but i am getting the following error after following all the steps

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Jsr199JavaCompiler.compile(Jsr199JavaCompiler.java:172)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateClass(Compiler.java:342)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:411)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:592)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:344)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:470)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:364)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:877)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:594)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1675)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

so how can i able to solve that or please tell any other way to cache the jsp at server side

actually i am developing an vxml application in which i am supplying text from xml dynamically so i wabt to cache some content on server side

caching.jsp page

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<vxml version="2.0" application = "eFMS_approot.vxml" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/vxml" xml:lang = "hi-IN">
<%@ taglib uri="Sun ONE Application Server Tags" prefix="mycache" %>

<mycache:cache>

<form id="Dealer_id_mobile_input">


<var name = "choice" />
    <block>
        <assign name = "node_name"  expr = "'DEALER_CALLER ID ENTRY NODE'" />
    </block>

    <!-- Entering the reg id -->
    <field name = "reg_id" type="digits?minlength=6;maxlength=6">
        <property name="termchar" value="*" />

        <prompt xml:lang= "lang_mode+'-IN'">
            <audio src = "../eFMS/audio/enterregidno.wav"  fetchhint="prefetch">
              Please enter your name
            </audio>
        </prompt> 
</field>
</form>
</mycache:cache>
</vxml
```

thanks

Comment: show the code with line number that causes this exception

Comment: <%@ taglib prefix="mycache" uri="Sun ONE Application Server Tags" %><mycache:cache>

<h1>this is jsp caching</h1>
</mycache:cache>     if i run this dummy code than i will get the above exception

Comment: Please edit your question with the code from your comment above.